# Maven plugin to convert tabs to spaces

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

Do you know a maven plugin to convert at buildtime tabs to spaces in source files ?

(as in AnyEdit Eclipse Plugin)

Answer (score 0):

FixCRLF Ant task seems to do that ... and can be attached to process-sources phase